# How do you check if a web application extension already exist

Tags: powershell, web-application

I can create a new web application extension using `New-SPWebApplicationExtension` but if it already exist I get an error with the message "The IIS Web Site you have selected is in use by SharePoint.  You must select another port or hostname.".

I tried using `Get-SPWebApplication` but it does not return the extensions. I know I could catch the thrown exception and react on it but I wonder if there is a more cleaver way, e.g. `Get-SPWebApplicationExtension` that I can use to check if it already exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `Get-SPAlternateURL`, it will return url from all zone then you will be know if one you are requesting being used or not

> The Get-SPAlternateURL cmdlet returns all alternate URLs that match
>   the scope given by either the optional Identity parameter or by a
>   combination of the optional WebApplication, Zone, or Resource
>   parameters. Each criterion that is added narrows the scope. If no
>   criteria are specified then all alternate URLs are returned.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607923.aspx